# Disable iOS double tap spacebar from browser

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, mobile, safari

In iOS, there is native functionality that whenever the user double taps the spacebar and there is already content in the input field, it replaces what should be a double space with a full stop and a space.

I'm using Angular and ng-change to check for invalid characters when the field gets changed.

My question is - is there any way from a browser point of view to disable this functionality? If not - is there any hacks/ways around it in which I could replace the full stop and the space because at the moment, when I double tap the spacebar it doesn't seem to fire the function bound to ng-change.

Comment: In theory you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uLf9Z/

Comment: Hmm yeah - but this disables backspace as well.

Comment: This works http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/YKz4N/

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
var prevTime = 0, prevKey = 0;
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    if (Date.now() - prevTime < 1000 && prevKey == 32 && e.keyCode == 32) {
        var txt = this.value.split("");
        if (txt[txt.length - 2] == ".") {
            txt[txt.length - 2] = " ";
            this.value = txt.join("");
        }
    }
    prevTime = Date.now(); prevKey = e.keyCode;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/YKz4N/